# What is the best way to pass a string delimiter to textString.characters.split?

Tags: swift2

I have an error when trying to split a string by a passed in parameter.

Example run.

```
./create-events-from-dvd-contents.swift --path /Volumes/ARCHIVE/DVD\ 1255/2451-01_LLA_Assets\ Folder\ Nov\ 2015/ --root-prefix DVD --job-meta-data-delimiter _
./create-events-from-dvd-contents.swift:72:69: error: cannot convert value of type '(String) -> Bool' to expected argument type '_Element' (aka 'Character')
            let jobMetaDataArray: Array<String> = jobFolder_.characters.split {$0 == delimiter}.map { String($0) } ;
```

The function:

```
func setJobNumberClientCodeAndJobTitleFromJobFolderGivenDelimiter( jobFolder_: String, delimiter_: String ) {

    let jobMetaDataArray: Array<String> = jobFolder_.characters.split {$0 == delimiter_}.map { String($0) } ;

    /* 
        ...
        */
}
```

If I hard code the parameter then it works.

Example:

func setJobNumberClientCodeAndJobTitleFromJobFolderGivenDelimiter( jobFolder_: String, delimiter_: String ) {

```
    let jobMetaDataArray: Array<String> = jobFolder_.characters.split {$0 == "_"}.map { String($0) } ;

    /* 
        ...
        */
}
```

What is the best way to pass a string delimiter to textString.characters.split ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer was to use a different function.

```
func setJobNumberClientCodeAndJobTitleFromJobFolderGivenDelimiter( jobFolder_: String, delimiter_: String ) {

    let jobMetaDataArray: Array<String> = jobFolder_.componentsSeparatedByString(delimiter_) ;

    /*
         ...

        */

}
```